# convergence or divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ 1}{n^3 \sin^2(n)}$ and similar series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pi

In one exercise of the Calculus textbook, Thomas' Calculus, 13th edition, there is an exercise (Section 10.4, 71) says it is not known yet if the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2(n)} $$
is convergent or not. The reason should be: given a fraction $p/q$ which is close to $\pi$, the term $$\frac{1}{p^3 \sin^2(p)}$$
can be large, and it should be very hard to estimate of the contributions of such terms.  For example, if $p/q=355/133$, the corresponding term
$$\frac{1}{355^3 \sin^2(355)}=24.598$$
and thus the partial sum has a jump at 355.

I have the following questions:

Question 1, Do we know anything new about this series?

Question 2: Do we know convergence/divergence about similar series, like
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \sin^2(n)}, \alpha>1?$$
Is there something special about the power $\alpha=3$ as in the exercise?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks @octave for the reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5100.pdf, this series is called Flint Hills series. I just found the link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1/172417#172417 in math overflow on the same question.

Comment: @marlasca23 Thanks. I am not sure how many terms you checked. For example, if $\alpha=2$, the term $1/n^2 \sin^2(n)$ when $n=5419351$ is about 23.3. So when $\alpha=2$, there partial sum can still have a huge jump at 5419351.

Comment: For question 2: don't have much time to take a look at it now, but https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5100.pdf should have some results about it

Comment: @octave Thanks for the reference. I didn't know it has a name.